# Dataset not being updated vb.net

Tags: vb.net, binding, dataset

While loading form i fill the dataset with following code:

```
Con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Congress.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Con.Open()

dAp1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from VotingRecords", Con)
DS.Tables.Add("VotingRecords")
dAp1.Fill(DS.Tables("VotingRecords"))

BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = myBS
myBS.DataSource = DS.Tables("VotingRecords")

Me.BillComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myBS, "BillNumber", True))
Me.CongressPersonComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myBS, "CID", True))
Me.VoteComboBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", myBS, "Vote", True))
```

here All Con, dAP1, DS, myBS variables are global or form level variables.

When save button is clicked:

```
Try
    myBS.EndEdit()
    dAp1.Update(DS.Tables("VotingRecords"))
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("Error")
End Try
```

Not sure why its showing me error; Error message:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection
>   with modified rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.... thanks for
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx

its the commandbuilder that i was missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `UpdateCommand` property on your `OleDbDataAdapter`.

```
dAp1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from VotingRecords", Con)
dAp1.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE VotingRecords SET Column1 = ?, Column2 = ? WHERE Column3 = ?")
dAp1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("Column1", column1OleDbType, column1Length, "Column1")
dAp1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("Column2", column2OleDbType, column2Length, "Column2")
dAp1.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("Column3", column3OleDbType, column3Length, "Column3")
dAp1.UpdateCommand.Parameters("Column3").SourceVerion = DataRowVersion.Original
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.updatecommand.aspx